# Run a operation throughout the application

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, gps

I have a app in which I am logging some data constantly once started, now its limited to the same screen. I want to run that operation throughout the app irrespective of the screen I am in. User can start and stop in that particular screen.Also that operation should run when I suspended the app in background.

Comment: Just create service/daemon. it will be ruined by OS and you application will communicated with this service and grab necessary data or apply settings.

Comment: Can you please put some demo code , so I can understand better.

Comment: It's difficult to add code, because you had to create client-server architecture and I support you use windows as you host system. here is link for service example - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/499465/Simple-Windows-Service-in-Cplusplus